# Magento Access denied for user error

Tags: magento

I decided to give a try to Magento. I have used my hosting provider´s service Simple Scripts to install it in a subdomain. After succesfull install a have tried to go to home page but this error has occured:
SQLSTATE[00000] [1045] Access denied for user: 'testing_1303@10.10.29.3' (Using password: YES)
I have searched google but found nothing. I have checked my data in app/etc/local.xml file. host, user, password, dbname everything is OK. I also checked minimal requirements with magento script and a I have passed all requirements.
Do you have any sugestions?

One more clue: I have renamed local.xml file to force Magento to install again, but it does not start the instalation. My browser throw this error: Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

SOLUTION:
And here is the solution with help of my hosting provider:
In the local.xml file put this as a host:

```
<host><![CDATA[127:0:0:1:/tmp/mysql50.sock]]></host>
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Magento problem at all.  Can you login in your database using those credentials, outside of Magento?

Comment: yes, I can login to my database outside Magento.

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer below?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION: And here is the solution with help of my hosting provider: In the local.xml file put this as a host:

```
<host><![CDATA[127:0:0:1:/tmp/mysql50.sock]]></host>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is almost definitely not an issue with Magento.

If you are sure your database credentials are correct then the problem probably lies in the fact that you are trying to connect to a non-local database server and the server does not allow remote connections.

Comment: In my admin for my domain I have created database with all the credentials I have put to local.xml file. So it must be local database connection

Comment: @Matop79: try using 127.0.0.1 instead then.

Comment: I have tried, but no luck. Ok, I am going to post to my hosting provider. Error seems to be there.

Answer (score 1):

Try emptying the `var/` folder. Maybe it's a cache issue.